# Couldn't access the variable outside loop Javascript

Tags: javascript

My Sample Code

```
 function testfunction(){
     var index = 0;
     $(string).find("data").each(function () {
         if(index == 0){
             var testVar    = 'test'; // Declaring a variable
         }
         index++;
     });
     console.log(typeof testVar); // Shows undefined
}
```

output : `undefined`

Here, I am not able to access the variable `testVar` outside the loop.

Anyone please let me know why this is happening, As I am creating a variable inside the function and accessing the same variable inside the same function.

Comment: `Function-level-scope`....

Comment: One more with `var` and function scope.

Comment: Your variable is within another function

Comment: Besides error, what is the code doing? `var index = 0;` and checking in the `each` `index == 0` will always be true.

Comment: "As I am creating a variable inside the function and accessing the same variable inside the same function" — You are not. There are two different functions there.